# Persistent Settings in Android Wear

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, persistence, wear-os

I started developing my first Android Wear watchface and have some problems understanding the concept of settings.

The user of my watchface should be able to set some preferences right on the watch - e.g. different colors.

But how should these settings be persisted on the watch? All the samples from Google use the Wearable.NodeApi.getLocalNode. But as far as I could understand, this is intended to synchronize settings between different(?) watches via the Internet. At least according to the guide on https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html

But does this mechanism also make the settings persistant, or do I have to implement the persistency myself (e.g. using SharedPreferences).

My view on this topic is, that if I change these settings e.g. via an UI on my phone, they get synchronized to all my watches via the DataItems - but on every watch I then have to store these settings. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the `DataApi` **will** persist data items locally between sessions - but it's less reliable, and a **lot** less convenient, than using `SharedPreferences`. As you noted, it's mostly meant for synchronizing data between devices; storing data is an afterthought. In my experience, data storage and synchronization are different enough that you need to implement both separately, using the APIs meant for each.

However, there's no sense reinventing the wheel. If your watch face will have configuration on both devices that needs both syncing to the other device and storing locally, may I suggest that you look at [PrefSyncService](https://github.com/StringMon/prefsyncservice). It's an open-source Android class that I designed for just this sort of use case.

To apply config changes from the phone to your running watch face, use an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`. In your `Engine`, use code something like this:

```
private class Engine 
        extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine
        implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private SharedPreferences settings;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);

        settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        ...other setup code...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        settings.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        ...other teardown code...

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences settings, String key) {
        ...update your watch face here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanaion. I will use this library - looks great.

Comment: Sorry but I have a follow up question: I understand that I store settings in the SharedPreferences and they are automatically synced to the phone e.g. The PrefSyncService needs to be started from an Activity or Service. But the watchafce is drawn from the CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine. How  do I propagate those changes to the Engine correctly, so I can apply those settings. Shoud I use the DataApi for communicating from the PrefSyncService or the ConfigActivity to the Engine? Or should I trigger some event in the Engine so the SharedPreferences are read again. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: I use an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`. I'll add it to my answer, and to the doc on the github repo.